# Create a new text file after writing several entries in an existing text file

Tags: delphi

I am trying to create a new .txt file after a certain number of entries in an existing .txt file. I would like to have, for example, 50 entries in my file and then, after that, I would like a new file to be created and that the entries continue in that new file. Let us say that I don't want my log files to be filled with a lot of lines, but to have instead more .txt files where entries would be divided.

Here is my example code:

```
procedure TForm1.Button3Click(Sender: TObject);

  function CountRows(Afilename: string): integer;
  var
    f: TextFile;
    i: integer;
  begin
    assignfile(f, afilename);
    reset(f);
    result := 0;
    while not eof(f) do
    begin
      readln(f);
      inc(result);
    end;
    closefile(f);
  end;

var
  f: TextFile;
  fileName: String;
  fs: Tformatsettings;
begin
  fs.shortdateformat := 'DD.MM.YYYY';
  fs.TimeSeparator := ':';
  filename := 'D:\LogLprf\LogLpFr ' + Datetostr(now, fs) + '.txt';
  assignfile(f, filename);
  if FileExists(filename) then
  begin
    if CountRows(filename)>=2 then
    begin
      filename := 'D:\LogLprf\LogLpFr ' + Datetostr(now, fs) +'1.txt';
      assignfile(f, filename);
      rewrite(f);
    end
    else
      append(f);
  end
  else
  begin
    rewrite(f);
  end;

  fs.ShortDateFormat := 'DD.MM.YYYY HH:mm:ss';
  Writeln(f, datetimetostr(now, fs)+'- '+'Some error...');
  closefile(f);
end;
```

With the above code I manage to create the first file and to create the second one if the limit of the entries is reached in the first file. But, the second file keeps re-creating every time. I know that is because I am calling `rewrite(f)` but I need that to create a new .txt file after the entries for the previous file reach their end. I have also tried calling the `fileexists(filename)` after `CountRows(filename)` but that is not a good solution as I will have a lot of nested if statements and that will not solve the issue if we need to create a lot of .txt files.
I have also tried going through loops, but that also doesn't solve the problem.
Any suggestions are wlcome...thank you

Comment: Of course you'd also need to inspect the second's file content (counting its lines/rows). Your current logic is to count rows of the **first** file to decide if the **second** file is created or appended. Do you want to continually create new files after 2 rows? That can be easily done with a loop (where `1` is an `Integer` to be increased).

Answer (score 1):

When you are defining the file name you are using [DateToStr](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/System.SysUtils.DateToStr) which only adds date information into your file name. So if you try to create new filename multiple times in one day you will always get the same file name since `DateToString` will return same result each time.

Instead of using `DateToString` you should use [DateTimeToString](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/System.SysUtils.DateTimeToString) as this would also include time information iinto the result and thus allow you to create multiple distinct file names in the same day. And unless you need to create multiple new file names in a single second you won't have any problem with this.

---

Another approach would be incrementally numbering your files so that each file name contains a unique number at the end.

You can find solution on how to achieve this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28220278/3636228)

---

Or you could also combine yours with automatic incremental numbering approach if you need more user friendly file naming system.

Comment: Thank you @SilverWarior for your answers and suggestions. The `datetimetostr` will not work for me as it will always create a new file with only one entry (in the case of my app). The second suggestion might be good (I have read the link that you sent) but I am afraid that it will still not work as I imagined. The third solution sounds interesting and I think that the answer that I found is something similar to what you suggested. If not, I would like to know more about what you meant by automatic incremental numbering approach

Comment: I'm guessing `DateTimeToString` doesn't work correctly for you because you failed to initialize `FormatSettings` correctly. Before using `FomratSettings` record you should call its [Create](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/System.SysUtils.TFormatSettings.Create) method first in order to populate format settings fields. There are two overloaded versions of this method that you can pass either `LocaleID` or `LocaleName` to them so that the format settings fields get populated with correct settings for that specific Locale.

Answer (score 0):

Please see the code that I found as a solution that suits me well...with the help of all the people commenting and posting to my question:

```
procedure TForm1.Button5Click(Sender: TObject);    
function SearchFiles(SearchDir, SearchFile:string):String;
var
  SearchRec: TSearchRec;
begin
  if FindFirst(SearchDir+SearchFile, faAnyfile, SearchRec)=0 then
    begin
      repeat
        result := SearchRec.Name
      until (findnext(SearchRec)<>0);
    end;
    FindClose(SearchRec);
end;
function GetFilesCount(SearchDir, SearchFile : String) : Integer;
var
  SearchRec: TSearchRec;
begin
  Result := 0;

  if FindFirst(SearchDir + SearchFile, faAnyFile xor faDirectory, SearchRec)= 0 then
  begin
    repeat
      Inc(Result);
    until (FindNext(SearchRec) <> 0);
    FindClose(SearchRec);
  end;
end;
var
  FileCont: TStringList;
  f:textfile;
  FileName, S: String;
  fs: Tformatsettings;
  SearchRec: TSearchRec;
  i:integer;
begin
  FileCont := TStringList.Create;
  try
    fs.shortdateformat := 'DD.MM.YYYY';
    fs.TimeSeparator := ':';
    if SearchFiles(Extractfilepath(application.ExeName),'LogLpFr '+datetostr(now,fs)+' .txt') = '' then
      begin
        Filename := Extractfilepath(application.ExeName) + 'LogLpFr '+ Datetostr(Now, fs) +' .txt';
        filecont.SaveToFile(filename);
      end
    else
      Filename := Extractfilepath(application.ExeName) + SearchFiles(Extractfilepath(application.ExeName),'LogLpFr '+datetostr(now,fs)+' *.txt');

    FileCont.LoadFromFile(FileName);
    if FileCont.Count >=2 then
      begin
       i := GetFilesCount(Extractfilepath(application.ExeName),'LogLpFr '+datetostr(now,fs)+' *.txt');
       Filename := Extractfilepath(application.ExeName) + 'LogLpFr '+Datetostr(Now, fs) +' '+i.ToString+'.txt';
       FileCont.Clear();
      end;


    fs.ShortDateFormat := 'DD.MM.YYYY HH:mm:ss';
    S := DateTimeToStr(Now(), fs) + '- ' + 'Some error...';
    FileCont.Add(S);
    FileCont.SaveToFile(Filename);
  finally
    FileCont.Free();
  end;
end;
```

I used a function `GetFilesCount` provided by @Ehab and added one similar function `SearchFiles` that will search for all the files and make sure that the last file is the one that we are using for writing. (My initial problem was that in my first code, I always worked with the same file...) My thanks to all that helped...

Answer (score 0):

Today I have a ruining Delphi7 so, here is a full working sample.

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, StdCtrls;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Btn1: TButton;
    Memo1: TMemo;
    procedure Btn1Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

  //Just a sample class not a production one
  //Each day has log files Like  21.12.2022_0001.txt, 21.12.2022_0002.txt, ...
  TSampleLoger = class
  private
    procedure SetWorkPath(const Value: string);
    procedure SetMaxLinesPerFile(const Value: Integer);
  protected
    FileCont: TStringList;
    Fs: TFormatsettings;
    FWorkPath : string;
    FLastFile : string;
    FFilesCount : Integer;
    FMaxLinesPerFile: Integer;

    //Make a full file name without extension eg.
    //(D:\LogLprf\21.12.2022)
    function MakeBaseFileName() : string;

    //Updates FLastFile & FFilesCount and returns New file name
    function MakeNewFileName() : string;

    //Make a full file name without extension eg.
    //(D:\LogLprf\21.12.2022_0099.txt)
    function MakeFileName(C : Integer) : string;

    //Returns Today last used log file if exists
    function GetLastFileName(): string;

    //Returns Files count for a specific date and last file used for that day
    //SearchFile Param. Value will be like [D:\LogLprf\21.12.2022_*.txt]
    function GetFilesCount(SearchFile : String; var LastFileName:String) : Integer;
  public
    constructor Create(APath:string); reintroduce;
    destructor Destroy; override;

    procedure WriteToLog(Msg:String);


    property LastFile : string read GetLastFileName;
    property WorkPath : string read FWorkPath write SetWorkPath;
    property MaxLinesPerFile : Integer read FMaxLinesPerFile write SetMaxLinesPerFile;
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;
```

the implementation section

```
implementation

{$R *.dfm}

function TSampleLoger.GetFilesCount(SearchFile : String; var LastFileName:String) : Integer;
var
  SearchRec: TSearchRec;
begin
  //Initial values
  Result := 0;
  LastFileName := '';

  if FindFirst(SearchFile, faAnyFile xor faDirectory, SearchRec)= 0 then
  begin
    repeat
      Inc(Result);
      LastFileName := SearchRec.Name;
    until (FindNext(SearchRec) <> 0);
    Windows.FindClose(SearchRec.FindHandle);
  end;
end;

constructor TSampleLoger.Create(APath: string);
begin
  inherited Create();
  WorkPath := APath;
  FileCont := TStringList.Create;

  FFilesCount := 0;
  FMaxLinesPerFile := 50;
end;

function TSampleLoger.GetLastFileName: string;
var
  S : string;
begin
  if FLastFile = '' then
  begin
    S := MakeBaseFileName() + '_*.txt';
    FFilesCount := GetFilesCount(s, FLastFile);
    FLastFile := FWorkPath + FLastFile;
  end;

  Result := FLastFile;
end;

function TSampleLoger.MakeBaseFileName() : string;
var
  Path : string;
begin
  Fs.ShortDateformat := 'DD.MM.YYYY';
  Result := FWorkPath + Datetostr(Date(), Fs);
end;

function TSampleLoger.MakeNewFileName() : string;
begin
  Inc(FFilesCount);
  FLastFile := MakeFileName(FFilesCount);
  Result := FLastFile;
end;

procedure TSampleLoger.WriteToLog(Msg:String);
var
  FileName, S: String;
begin
  FileName := GetLastFileName();

  //Do we have a file for today?
  if FileName <> '' then
  begin
    //Load file contents
    FileCont.LoadFromFile(FileName);

    //Get ready to start new file if we reached the Maximum line count per file
    if FileCont.Count >=  FMaxLinesPerFile then
      FileName := '';
  end;

  //Start new file if we don't have one
  if FileName = '' then
  begin
    FileName := MakeNewFileName();
    FileCont.Clear();
  end;

  Fs.TimeSeparator := ':';
  Fs.ShortDateFormat := 'DD.MM.YYYY HH:mm:ss';
  S := DateTimeToStr(Now(), Fs) + '- ' + Msg;
  FileCont.Add(S);
  FileCont.SaveToFile(Filename);
end;

procedure TSampleLoger.SetWorkPath(const Value: string);
begin
  FWorkPath := Value;
  if FWorkPath[Length(FWorkPath)] <> '\' then
    FWorkPath := FWorkPath + '\';
end;

function TSampleLoger.MakeFileName(C: Integer): string;
const
  Fmt = '_%4.4U.txt';
begin
  //add counter and extension to file name
  Result := MakeBaseFileName() + Format(Fmt,[C]);
end;

destructor TSampleLoger.Destroy;
begin
  FileCont.Free();
  inherited;
end;

procedure TSampleLoger.SetMaxLinesPerFile(const Value: Integer);
begin
  FMaxLinesPerFile := Value;

  //At least one line per file
  if FMaxLinesPerFile < 1 then
    FMaxLinesPerFile := 1;
end;


procedure TForm1.Btn1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  Logger : TSampleLoger;
  i : Integer;
  S : string;
begin
  Logger := TSampleLoger.Create('D:\LogLprf\');   
  try
    for i := 1 to 320 do
    begin
      //Write a randome Msg to log
      S := 'Error ' + IntToStr(GetTickCount());
      Logger.WriteToLog(S);

      Memo1.Lines.Add(Logger.LastFile + ' === ' + S);
      Application.ProcessMessages();
    end;
  finally
    Logger.Free();
  end;
end;

end.
```

Comment: Delphi 7 is not "_ruining_". It is not a full **example**, as no instance of your class is actually used. And I fear OP is not that much into OOP to figure out how this would help him at all, let alone use pieces of it.

Answer (score -2):

I don't have a running environment right now to test your code, but I think you can try something like that :

```
function GetFilesCount(SearchDir, SearchFile : String) : Integer;
var
  SearchRec: TSearchRec;
begin
  Result := 0;

  if FindFirst(SearchDir + SearchFile, faAnyFile xor faDirectory, SearchRec)= 0 then
  begin
    repeat
      Inc(Result);
    until (FindNext(SearchRec) <> 0);
    Windows.FindClose(SearchRec.FindHandle);
  end;
end;

    procedure TForm1.Btn3Click(Sender: TObject);
    var
      FileCont: TStringList;
      FileName, S: String;
      fs: Tformatsettings;
      C : Integer;
    begin
      FileCont := TStringList.Create;
      try
        fs.shortdateformat := 'DD.MM.YYYY';
        fs.TimeSeparator := ':';
        FileName := 'D:\LogLprf\LogLpFr ' + Datetostr(Now(), fs) + '.txt';
    
        if FileExists(FileName) then
        begin
          FileCont.LoadFromFile(FileName);
          if FileCont.Count >=2 then
          begin
            //Count previous log files.
            C := GetFilesCount('D:\LogLprf\', 'LogLpFr*.txt');
            Inc(C);
            Filename := 'D:\LogLprf\LogLpFr ' + Datetostr(Now(), fs) +  + IntToStr(C) + '.txt';
            FileCont.Clear();
          end;
        end;
    
        fs.ShortDateFormat := 'DD.MM.YYYY HH:mm:ss';
        S := DateTimeToStr(Now(), fs) + '- ' + 'Some error...';
        FileCont.Add(S);
        FileCont.SaveToFile(Filename);
      finally
        FileCont.Free();
      end;
    end;
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer @Ehab. I have just ran your code and it produces the same result as my, except that you are using `TStringList` instead...

Comment: No explanation of your choices, no comments in code... just code and "_try that_". Can't you elaborate or overthink you answer?

Comment: Sorry @petar-sindjic, I edited my sample and added a function to count previous log files and use this count in new file name. You will need to include windows in uses and maybe shellapi unit. I can't try this code because I don't have a running environment with Delphi right now.

Comment: No need to apologize @Ehab...I have tested your code and it still doesn't do what I want it to do. But, I have found a solution that suits me well. The `GetFilesCount` function that you provided helped me. And also, I have read the info from @SilverWarior that gave me some ideas to try. I will post my code as answer....